# Trouble installing freeglut-3-dev - still maintained?

Tags: glut, freeglut

When I run `apt-get install freeglut3-dev` I get a bunch of 404 Not Found errors. How can I run my glut application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install [`freeglut3-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freeglut3-dev) package fine in Ubuntu 14.04.1. 404 Not Found looks like a server problem. Try running `apt-get update` to update the package lists.